# Unity 2D, How To Make an Orbital Gravity Like at Angry Birds Space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Does someone know how to make a planet with orbital gravity exactlly like Angry Birds Space planet gravity?
I want that the object will move around the planet only when it get into a field.
I also want that the object will land on the ground after some rounds like angry birds space.
A script will help me.

*I use c# and unity 2d.

Edit: in the answer Fredric Schön send me a script but when the object land on planets, it doesn't stop to rotate aroud the planet. And how can i make the object to fall slowly to the planet and stay in the gravitation radius like at angry birds space?

Comment: "Math." You do it with math.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the [ask] link. Start writing the code and if you have a problem ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D), typeof(CircleCollider2D))]
public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0.1f, 50f)]
    public float gravitation = 0.45f;
    [Range(4, 50)]
    public float gravitationRadius = 11f;
    [Range(0f, 10f)]
    public float rotationSpeed = 0.9f;

    private CircleCollider2D gravitationTrigger;

    void Start()
    {
        gravitationTrigger = GetComponents<CircleCollider2D>()[1];
        gravitationTrigger.isTrigger = true;
        gravitationTrigger.radius = gravitationRadius / transform.localScale.x;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed);

        foreach (var objectInVicinity in objectsInRange)
        {
            if (objectInVicinity == null) {
                objectsInRange.Remove(objectInVicinity);
                break;
            }

            float dist = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, objectInVicinity.transform.position);
            float gravitationFactor = 1 - dist / gravitationRadius;
            Vector2 force = (transform.position - objectInVicinity.transform.position).normalized * gravitation * gravitationFactor;
            objectInVicinity.AddForce(force);
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, gravitationRadius);
    }

    private List<Rigidbody2D> objectsInRange = new List<Rigidbody2D>();
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        var rb = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            objectsInRange.Add(rb);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        var rb = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            objectsInRange.Remove(rb);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you create objects with a trigger circle collider. When an object hits the collider they will enter the planet's vicinity for applying gravity (you set the force/planet as well). More gravity the closer you are. If you leave, all gravitational forces are removed.

Here's a gif of the code in action; you can see the gravitational pull of the smaller planet:
[image]

[And link to the game](https://ldjam.com/events/ludum-dare/42/not-enough-space-2)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you not use the standard gravitational attraction formula (G·M·m/r²) modified with a collider to trigger it? I'm sure there's a good reason and I think it would be worth explaining that in terms of trade-offs in game design.

Comment: @Fredrik_Schön                                                                  Can you help me with my other problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't played Angry Birds.

Comment: @Fredrik_Schön this is a link to short video of the game: youtu.be/L0twZbUF6Ic Can you answer my question? You will help me a lot. :)

Comment: Is your problem that the gravitational force is too high...? Simply lower it. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what to help with. If you're having issues with it keep rolling after it has hit the surface, simply add a check and lower the gravity then, or add a lot of friction to the material of the planet, so it doesn't glide around.